# how to align text boxes HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Text is going down in a stairs sort of way. Here is the code. I have seen a ton of posts but clearly none are working for me. New to code so would appreciate some help. Wanting to align it in a horizontal line.

```
    <div class="text">
    <p class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
      possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
      response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    </div>

p.text1 {
 color: white;
 margin-right: 1250px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

p.text2 {
 color: white;
 margin-right: 600px;
 margin-left: 600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

p.text3 {
 color: white;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 1200px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can help of `display: table-cell` Property.

```css
.text1,.text2,.text3 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
      possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
      response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using `white` color for `p` . And the OP mentioned he/she is new in coding so I would suggest not to specify the color `p` to `#000` :)

Comment: @threeFatCat,  Thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox solution

```css
.text {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.text p {
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.text3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
  <p class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
  <p class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem but I suggest you to use "flex". You just need to set the display properties of the container on "flex", flex direction defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container and "justify-content" defines the alignment along the main axis.

```css
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: "column";
  justify-content: "space-around";
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p.text1 {
  background: #bbb;
}

p.text2 {
  background: #888;
}

p.text3 {
  background: #555
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
  <p class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
  <p class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.text1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: green;
}

.text3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <div class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
      possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
      response team, we can meet every demand.</div>
    <div class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</div>
    <div class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</div>
</div>
```

The above snippet should work, just an example. You can add more css to your classes yourself and remove the background :).

There is even another way to do it but it is not [supported by older browsers:](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1; /*grow*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Left div</div>
  <div>Middle div</div>  
  <div>Right div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's 2017. Don't use floats.

Comment: Thats why there is a second suggestion :)

Comment: It's supported by all browsers still under manufacturer support. Anyway, that should be the first solution, with floats maybe given as a fallback for cases in which it is unavoidable to support obsolete browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Set display and justify property for parent and it will give you desired output

```css
.text{
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
  }
.text1 {
 color: black;
 width: 30%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

.text2 {
 color: black;
 width: 30%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

.text3 {
 color: black;
 width: 30%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p class="text1">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
      possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
      response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text2">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
    <p class="text3">We strive to produce the most highest grade of product 
     possible. Efficiency is our key, with the support of our team and our fast 
     response team, we can meet every demand.</p>
  </div>
```